# Workstatin 11 Vmware tool on Centos 7 guest

Tags: centos, vmware-workstation, vmware-tools

I installed kernel-headers package and VMware-tool installer still complains about not valid path for kernel header files no matter what path I put in.

```
/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-229.1.2.el7.x86_64/include
/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-229.1.2.el7.x86_64/kernel
/usr/include/Linux
```

I also tried one suggestion after searching on the internet:

```
ln -s 
/usr/src/kernel/$(uname -r)/include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h  
/usr/src/kernel/$(uname -r)/include/linux/version.h
```

Comment: This site is for programming questions *only*.

Answer (score 0):

this question was addressed at [unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/215694/empty-kernel-directory-but-kernel-headers-are-installed).

`uname -r` can give something different than where the headers are installed. for instance in my build `uname -r` resolves to '3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64' whereas my headers were in '/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-229.11.1.el7.x86_64'.

this should work as long as you did not try to symbolically link the entire directory...

```
export kernel_headers=`ls -hd /usr/src/kernels/3*`
sudo ln -s ${kernel_headers}/include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h ${kernel_headers}/include/linux/version.h
```